# Scrapy shell does not work for https://www.target.com.au/

Tags: html, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I have tested that my shell works for other websites, but refuse to work on target.

```
raise self.value.with_traceback(self.tb)
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
```

Comment: I called: scrapy shell "https://www.target.com.au/" --nolog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the site is ignoring requests based on your user agent string.

This works:

```
scrapy shell target.com.au --nolog --set=USER_AGENT=Mozilla
```